# Ive had to reinstall Metamask and I have my seed phrase, but now shows a different account number to the original

Tags: metamask

would appreciate some help.
Ive seen some similar questions but the answers have not helped me.  I have been using Metamask for certain tokens one of which is CSWAP, which i have also staked.
When I stake, it is linked to my original account number on metamask.
Ive reinstalled and entered my seed phrase but now shows a different account number and now the CSWAP stake account shows no staking tokens as it is a different account.
There was also USDT in the account.
Tried a few options like Vault decrypter but nothing.
I really dont know what else to do.
Extremely frustrated.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "account address' when you wrote "account number"?!

Comment: Did you try adding extra addresses in Metamask? Maybe the address you were using wasn't the first one. The other possibility is that the seed phrase doesn't correspond to that address.